# What are these symbols (switch lookalike + and half a disk next to small pulse)?

Tags: schematics, symbol, circuits

I'm told as a new employee in a French company to fully understand and familiarize myself with two circuits to later apply many modifications to them. I was given the schematics and I can't understand what some of the components are.

(screenshot 1 is from schematic 1 and screenshot 2 is from schematic 2)
I can post the entire schematics if needed.

[image: screenshot from circuit 1]

[image: screenshot from circuit 2]

Comment: Are you sure you have permission from your employer to post their schematics to web? Also why can't you ask your co-workers about the schematics and components used?

Comment: You might want to read the product books from companies such as Telemechanique to familiarize yourself with industrial relays, pushbutton switches, emergency stop switches and the like.

Comment: They look like E-stops to me. French company = EDF?

Comment: The symbol is for a 'latched mushroom emergency off' switch. The 'disk' indicates a 'mushroom' push button. The 'small pulse' indicates it's a latching type. Here's a reference resource https://symbols.radicasoftware.com/225/iec-symbols.

Comment: @Justme Yes, I do have permission. it's a small company and the employee who made the schematics left the company.

Comment: @Kartman Thank you, that is super useful.

Comment: @Andyaka it is not EDF. it's a very small company and I don't know what E-stops are. Thankfully others have explained.

Comment: @vu2nan thank you this is the answer I'm looking for. and that link will be extremely useful to me. cheers.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first picture is a relay where the square represents the coil and the tilted lines represent contacts. A 90 degree bend on the line that meets the contact like in the "ri" example means *normally closed* (NC) and the lack of one means *normally open* (NO).

The half circle symbols represent mechanical mushroom push-buttons, like the ones used for emergency stops. The triangle on the line indicates a latching function - that is, the switch will stay pressed when activated and has to be released by a pull or twist motion.

Emergency stop buttons need to have a latching function since safety regulators require that they must be restored at the point where they were activated. Also it is common that if they have several contacts, as in your examples, these are forcibly guided - meaning both are mechanically guaranteed to follow each other. They are almost always NC too, so that pressing them breaks the stop circuit.